# Conan saying "No package 'fontenc' found"

Tags: linux, debian, conan

i'm trying to use **Conan** to dev a c++ project (on a debian 10.x 64 bits).
I've setup my `conanfile.txt` as follows :

```
[requires]
portaudio/19.7.0@bincrafters/stable
opus/1.3.1
qt/5.15.2
asio/1.19.2
sqlite3/3.36.0

[options]
*:shared=True

[imports]
lib, *.so* -> lib
bin, *.dll -> ./bin
lib, *.dylib* -> ./bin

[generators]
cmake
```

But when i use `conan install ..` (inside a build directory ofc), i get the following error:

```
No package 'fontenc' found
```

I don't see any similar problems on google and i'm new to Conan so i'm a bit lost.

Comment: Did you enabled system package installation? https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#systempackagetool Have to export ` CONAN_SYSREQUIRES_MODE=enabled` I seems like Conan is advising you about missing system packages, but you didn't allow to install

Answer (score 2):

> No package 'fontenc' found

"package fontenc" means `package config file fontenc.pc`

The file `fontenc.pc` is provided by the Debian package `libfontenc-dev` : `apt install libfontenc-dev` https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=fontenc.pc

Searching for a package name, when you know a file name : Please use the above Debian search page, or use `apt-file` →

```
apt install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search fontenc.pc
apt-file search ice.pc               ## ref. comment
```

https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ice.pc

Installing multiple packages: `apt install package package package package`

Comment: It works, thanks. But now I have another package missing named 'ice', i wish i don't have a lot of dependencies missing, do you know if there is a way to install all dependencies in a few commands ?

Comment: How would you go along using 'dnf' package manager to avoid this issue ?

Comment: HCKRMVT : Fedora, CentOS → decide a package name → `dnf provides */fontenc.pc` ............ `# dnf install libfontenc-devel`